# Custom APP_STORAGE with files inside it in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am using Google App Engine Standard Env, and I have my APP_STORAGE set to /tmp.

Now I have a file in the `tmp` folder, (https://github.com/spatie/laravel-analytics) but I get

`` Could not find a credentials file at `/tmp/app/analytics/service-account-credentials.json`. ``

Locally, it does work if I do not change my storage folder and keep it as `storage`. 
I have tried renaming my storage folder to tmp, without any luck too.

It looks like the tmp folder is not getting the storage folder items. What is the best way to debug/solve this?

Answer (score 0):

If this error occurs on the server, check read/write permissions for tmp folder.

Log into server and type: `ls -l [path to tmp]`

Note: good practice is to give 775 permissions (read/write permissions to owner and web-server) ONLY to storage folder. Rest should keep 755.

 In your case, maybe tmp folder is not writable by web server.

Answer (score 0):

See the answer to your question [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/php-docs-samples/issues/1085#issuecomment-624803296). TLDR is you should configure the location of your JSON to be somewhere else.